# How to read the Azure App Configuration in Service Fabric ASP.NET Core Stateless Web API?

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, azure-service-fabric, asp.net-core-3.1, azure-app-configuration

I need help to read the App Configuration in Service Fabric ASP.NET Core Stateless Web API. In the Normal ASP.NET Core Web API, we can use the Host CreateDefaultBuilder to read the config and use it in the Startup and other classes. If I try to inject in the Service Fabric Web API, it does not work. The Program.cs contains only the following.

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                try
                {
                    // The ServiceManifest.XML file defines one or more service type names.
                    // Registering a service maps a service type name to a .NET type.
                    // When Service Fabric creates an instance of this service type,
                    // an instance of the class is created in this host process.
    
                    ServiceRuntime.RegisterServiceAsync("EmailAPIType",
                        context => new EmailAPI(context)).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    
                    ServiceEventSource.Current.ServiceTypeRegistered(Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id, typeof(EmailAPI).Name);
    
    
                    // Prevents this host process from terminating so services keeps running. 
                    Thread.Sleep(Timeout.Infinite);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    ServiceEventSource.Current.ServiceHostInitializationFailed(e.ToString());
                    throw;
                }
            }
```

And the startup.cs contains

```
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    
    namespace EmailAPI
    {
        public class Startup
        {
            public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
            {
                Configuration = configuration;
            }
    
            public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
    
            // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
            public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
            {
                services.AddControllers();
            }
    
            // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
            public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
            {
                if (env.IsDevelopment())
                {
                    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                }
    
                app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    
                app.UseRouting();
    
                app.UseAuthorization();
    
                app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
                {
                    endpoints.MapControllers();
                });
            }
        }
    }
```

I tried to inject Host CreateDefaultBuilder in program.cs

```
Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                    webBuilder.ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
                        {
                            var settings = config.Build();




                            config.AddAzureAppConfiguration(options =>
                            {
                                options.Connect(ConnectionString)
                                    .Select(ConfigValues).TrimKeyPrefix(qualtricsAppConfigPrefix + ":")
                                    .UseFeatureFlags();
                            });
                        })
                        .UseStartup<Startup>());
```

I am running out of Ideas how to do. In Azure Function App we can do it in Startup, not sure how we can handle in Service Fabric ASP.NET Core Web API. Any examples please.

I have uploaded the sample project created in One Drive. Here is the link to it.

```
https://1drv.ms/u/s!Au2rKbF-hqWY61pykRlWRTI4DB8t?e=vz0c8z
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out. For anyone who is interested here is it. If you have any better way to do it please let me know

```
    public class Startup
    {
        private static string prefix = "";

        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            ConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder();

            configurationBuilder
                .AddEnvironmentVariables()
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", false, false)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables();


            var builder = configurationBuilder.Build();

            configurationBuilder.AddAzureAppConfiguration(o => AddApplicationKeysAppConfiguration(o, builder));
            builder = configurationBuilder.Build();

            configuration = builder;

            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        private static void AddApplicationKeysAppConfiguration(AzureAppConfigurationOptions options, IConfigurationRoot configuration)
        {
            var environment = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT");
            environment = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(environment) ? Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("Environment") : environment;


            string connectionString = "";

            options.Connect(connectionString)
                .Select($"{prefix}*", environment).TrimKeyPrefix(prefix + ":")
                .UseFeatureFlags(flagOptions =>
                {
                    flagOptions.Label = environment;
                });
        }



        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllers();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
    }
}
```